# Postback when session Expires in Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, postback

On one of my pages I have a `div` that uses AJAX to load content asynchronously.
When a session expires the user is supposed to be redirected back to the login screen. However, when the session expires and the AJAX call is triggered the login page gets put inside the `div`. What I want is for the user to be redirected back to the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can inspect the content you get back from the AJAX call to see if there is anything that defines it to be the login page (maybe a unique element with an id)? If that is the case, you can perform a redirect.

Something like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(html) {
      var element = jQuery(html).find("div#loginDiv");

      if(element.length > 0) {
         //perform redirect. if a matching id is found the count will not be 0
      }

      else {
         //insert content
      }      
   },
   ...
});
```